# How to toggle calendar.google.enableEmailInvitations to true in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, plugins, calendar, gmail, google-calendar

Within the context of the [Accept and Decline button missing in thunderbird when receiving an invitation](https://superuser.com/q/489189/977796) where an answer in part explains:

> Using the [config editor](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/config-editor), simply set
> `calendar.google.enableEmailInvitations` to true.  You may also want
> to set `calendar.google.sendEventNotifications` to false to avoid the
> possibility of an old bug that sent new events instead of
> notifications; I've not tested this.  Then, restart thunderbird.

How is `calendar.google.enableEmailInvitations` toggled to `true`?

There should be an option to open `Preferences` and then select "advanced" which was either changed, from when the question was asked, or I'm simply not seeing it.

Comment: The actual(?) problem of yours, getting the accept/decline button back, can be solved by calendar.itip.showImipBar = true. I added this as answer to the question you linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking how to get to the config editor?

Open preferences and scroll to the bottom.

[image]

Comment: thanks, I was looking in the calendar option

Comment: @NicholasSaunders it baffled me the first time I tried to find it